# redirect to new page but keep same url

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I'm trying to achieve the following

`http://domain.com/products/code.php` ---> `http://domain.com/products/name.php`
However, I want the url in the address bar to remain `http://domain.com/products/code.php` despite  showing the page `http://domain.com/products/name.php`.

I have tried to play around with this but it didn't give me the expected result:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/code.php
RewriteRule (.*) /products/name.php [L]
```

I would love some help, thanks :)

**UPDATE:** /Sorry, forgot to mention /code and /name are files not directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/code/
RewriteRule (.*) /products/name/$1 [L]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^products/code/(.*)$ /products/name/$1 [L]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^products/code.php$ /products/name.php [L]
```

Comment: no luck, please look at my amendments to the question